# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on a initialized Vector

Tags: java, vector, indexoutofboundsexception

I have this:

```
public class DoubleList<Key, Elem> implements ADTDoubleList<Key, Elem> {

    private Vector<Node<Key, Elem>> leftRight = new Vector<Node<Key, Elem>>(2);
    private int[] numLeftNumRight = new int[2];

    public DoubleList() {
        this.leftRight.set(0, null);
        this.leftRight.set(1, null);
        this.numLeftNumRight[0] = 0;
        this.numLeftNumRight[1] = 0;
    }
}
```

and it throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

I don't know why. Could someone help me?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896758/initial-size-for-the-arraylist and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/how-to-prevent-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-in-java. Note that it's recommended to use `ArrayList` instead of `Vector` in new Java code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set an element in a `Vector` or any other `List` if that index isn't already occupied.  By using `new Vector<Node<Key, Elem>>(2)` you're ensuring that the vector initially has the *capacity* for two elements, but it is still empty and so `get`ting or `set`ting using any index won't work.

In other words, the list hasn't grown big enough for that index to be valid yet.  Use this instead:

```
this.leftRight.add(null);  //index 0
this.leftRight.add(null);  //index 1
```

You could also do:

```
this.leftRight.add(0, null);
this.leftRight.add(1, null);
```

Comment: Much better answer with the constructor explanation.